# Rails polymorphic aliased associations

Tags: ruby, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to try set up this association:

```
# app/models/course.rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subjectable, polymorphic: true
end

# app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, as: :subjectable
end

# app/models/campus.rb
class Campus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, as: :subjectable
end
```

But this did not read very well in the code.

```
#this seems fine
campus = Campus.last
campus.courses 

#this dosent make much sense gramatically 
student = Student.last
student.courses
```

Campuses offer Courses, but Students don't have courses they have subjects. Now they are the same thing under the covers they just don't read well.

How could I get it so that `student.subejects` would yield the same result as `student.courses`?

Comment: `alias_method :subjects, :courses` or `alias subjects courses`.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ don’t use hashrocket syntax for hashes having symbolic keys, it has been deprecated like a decade ago. Use `as: :subjectable` instead.

Comment: You are right, I did copy the example above from another post, just modified the question to get the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much @mudasobwa

Comment: Then maybe you might need to read the docs for `has_many` since `as` parameter does exactly what you want; I omitted the obvious answer because your copied code already had it and I assumed you are aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can name the association as you want, you don't have to mach the associated class.

In this case, you have to tell ActiveRecord what the pointed class is :

```
# app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects, as: :subjectable, class_name: 'Course'
end
```